# How to fetch unique records from database?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure

```
album
id ---- albumname
1   General
3   Sports
9   Activities
gallery
id --- ablumid--- image_thumb  --              image_full
1   1   uploads/1358401616.jpg  uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358401616.jpg
2   1   uploads/1358401641.jpg  uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358401641.jpg
3   1   uploads/1358402071.jpg  uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358402071.jpg
4   3   uploads/1358402334.jpg  uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358402334.jpg
```

The problem is i have too many images for a singe gallery.

Here is my mysql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT gl.catid as gallery_cat_id, ab.albumname,gl.imagest 
FROM albums as ab 
INNER JOIN gallery as gl  ON ab.id=gl.catid 
order by ab.albumname ASC
```

Here is the result

```
gallery_id  albumname   image_full
38      Activities       uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358424428.jpg
41      Activities       uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358424483.jpg
40      Activities       uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358424468.jpg
39      Activities       uploads/thumbs/thumb_1358424446.jpg
```

The query show all records from gallery table i added DISTINCT in query but it is not working.
Can anyone tell me what i missed here?

Comment: That looks like four unique rows to me

Comment: Explain what you need. Distinct albumname?

Comment: What is the desired result of the query?

Comment: I need to show the album. actually i have three albums. i need to show 3 album with  single images  inside the albums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a single image (no matter what) for every album, you could use GROUP BY clause, to group by album id:

```
SELECT gl.catid as gallery_cat_id, ab.albumname, gl.imagest 
FROM
  albums as ab 
  INNER JOIN gallery as gl
  ON ab.id=gl.catid 
GROUP BY ab.id
order by ab.albumname ASC
```